# Toshiba Satellite L850 power adapter

Tags: power, adapter

My Toshiba Satellite L850 power adapter gets extremely hot when I am using my laptop. I have noticed recently it seems to be getting worse. I make a point of unplugging it from the mains in case it starts a fire. Does it need replacing?

Comment: Yes. They should not get hot. It will only get worse and may be a fire risk.

Comment: A lot of power adapters do get very hot, but if its becoming worrying, then of course you should replace it!

@DavidPostill Mine is hot to the touch, bought it brand new a day ago, as was all the ones I previously owned. Realistically, it can get hot, but if its becoming a fire hazard than it should be replaced

Comment: @Tealkine I have a four year old laptop. The power adapter is still cool to the touch (it has been on for 12 hours today). **Warm is OK, hot is not.**

Comment: Relevant: [How can I cool down a laptop power supply?](http://superuser.com/q/317736)

Comment: @Nyla Define "extremely hot"  can you hold your fingers on it? for how long? Any signs of the plastic case melting or distorting?

Comment: This is often an indication of a bad battery or charging circuit more than a bad adapter... If the battery is more than 2 years old I would replace it.

Comment: Hello, it gets so hot that if it accidentally touches my leg, i feel like I have burnt myself and it feels as hot as my hot water bottle after putting boiling water in it.  Shall I try to change the battery first and then if no change the adapter ?

Comment: I do have gadget insurance on it but the excess is £50.00. It's cheaper to buy a battery, if all else fails, I can also ask the insurance to take a look. I forgot to mention, no melting or distortion of battery look wise as yet!!!